# Flex cookie-like storage

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex4

Does an AIR app built with Flex have something similar to a browser cookie?
I want the app to remember a simple value, like date when the app was last opened. I'd rather not create a SQlite database just for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's called a [local shared object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object).

```
var someData:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("namethisanything");
```

now you have accessed some cookie... check if it's defined first, then update/set it. `someData.data` is a dynamic object at this point. It might have properties stored... it might not. To assign a value do this:

```
someData.data.lastOpened = new Date();
```

now to save the cookie, `someData.flush()`

Comment: Aha, thanks Jonathan. Does that get deleted somehow (like the browser cookie does) or is it up to the app to do that?

Comment: @Francisc No they aren't automatically cleared by any mechanism.  Here's some more details: http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Shared+Objects

Comment: Another useful note. Local shared objects are independent of the browser. You can create a LSO in one browser, close the browser, open up the app in another browser and still have access to the same LSO created in the first browser. I actually took advantage of that in a shopping cart app, the cart contents were maintained across browsers. This doesn't apply to AIR, but an interesting note.

Comment: Clearing cookies in most newer browsers DOES actually clear the cookies... but I'm not sure if that applies to AIR.

Comment: Another intersting note to add is that shared objects work on mobile devices, making it easier to save, for example, user profiles locally

Comment: While we're making interesting notes, if you want to store something more securely, there's also the AIR-only [EncryptedLocalStore](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html). It works the same way but encrypts its contents.

Comment: Clearing cookies will NOT clear LSOs. They are stored in an OS specific location, and you either need to clear it with code, or manually. With code, assuming a LSO variable named lso, lso.clear(), will clear the data and remove it from the file system.

Comment: @ahillman3 I'm not sure about AIR... but flash cookies ARE cleared by most modern browsers when cookies are cleared. This was a change made in Flash 10.3 I believe. If you don't belive me, look [at wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_shared_object) under "browser control".

Comment: @ahillman3 here's an article about it: http://linearfix.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/new-adobe-flash-player-10-3-allows-quick-clearing-of-flash-cookies/